# Is comparing the differences between each vector in a triangle enough to determine if it is isosceles?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Given a triangle with the vectors $A,B,C$, if you want to determine if it is isosceles, you need to check if two sides have the same length.

My first thought was to calculate the distance between each vector, which involves calculating the norm of the difference vector - that is:

$$|| A - B|| = \sqrt{(A-B)\cdot(A-B)} \\ ||A - C|| = \sqrt{(A-C)\cdot(A-C)} \\ ||B - C|| = \sqrt{(B-C)\cdot(B-C)}$$

And see if two results are equal.

However, that's quite a bit of legwork right there. I was wondering if it would be *sufficient* to just compare vector differences:

$$A-B\\ A - C\\ B - C$$

and perhaps

$$B-A\\ C-A\\ C-B$$

too.

Which may or may not be more lightweight. So my question is: **is comparing the differences between each vector in the triangle enough to determine if it is isosceles?**

Comment: In a sense it is, since if you know the differences you can find the norms of the differences. By the way, in your (correct) method, there is no need to take square roots. So it is not as painful as it looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is considering that the vectors A,B,C you are talking of are position vectors, and not the vectors representing the sides of the triangle.